# In Jupyter Notebook, pressing Tab causes a grey line to appear. How do I make whitespace appear instead?

Tags: python, jupyter

[image: Image Here]

Until recently, when pressing Tab to indent, Jupyter Notebook would insert 4 spaces, which is fine. Recently however, it instead inserts a small grey line instead of the whitespace. How do I go back to how it was? This is genuinely ruining my experience with it.

I am honestly not sure what to try, Google has no satisfactory answers.

Comment: If it worked before and doesn't work now, perhaps sharing the relevant versions would help. Also, a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Maybe add an image to better visualize what you mean.

Comment: Sure thing. I have added an image, although StackOverflow has forced it to be an Imgur link. The version of Jupyter being used is v6.5.3.

Comment: That looks like how a literal tab might be visualized. Are you getting a literal tab character? Does Settings → Text Editor Indentation show you an option to use tabs vs. spaces?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a literal tab character instead of 4 whitespaces. I have the option to use 4 spaces rather than tabs in Text Editor Indentation active.